# Using autobind without LDAPI

Tags: linux, centos, ldap, openldap

I am trying to automate the installation of my OpenLDAP servers.

Currently packages get installed (openldap-clients, openldap-servers) and started with their default configurations.

I have a LDIF file, that is supposed to modify the cn=config database.

I would like to know how can I use ldapmodify to apply my modifications without having to change anything in the configuration first (enable nsldapi, olcRootPW, etc...).

Is it possible to striclty rely on the fact that my user is root ? When I see this line I guess it's possible, but I didn't find the way to do it yet

```
olcAccess: {0}to *  by dn.base="gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth" manage  by * none
```

I think what I am looking for is called AutoBind, but it seems like it stil requires LDAPI to be enabled first.

Answer (score 0):

By default, when installing OpenLDAP packages on CentOS, the ldapi is not enabled.

You can verify that by looking at the `/var/run/openldap/slapd.args`, output looks like this

```
/usr/bin/slapd -h ldap:/// -u ldap
```

thus `ldapapp -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f xxx.ldif` failing.

One need to enable ldapi for its openldap servers. To so so simply edit `/etc/sysconfig/ldap` and set `SLAPD_LDAPI=yes`.

Restart the OpenLDAP server and rerun the command. It should work fine.